# I want an output where if the user inputs [1] he will be able to insert a new word to the existing list. If [2] the program will shutdown

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to input `[1]` and enter a new word to append the  existing words at list '''words''' in shuffle pattern.

```
import random

words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'coconut', 'strawberry', 'lime']
old_word = []

while True:
    choice = int(input('Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: '))
    if choice == 2:
        break
    
    elif choice == 1:
        new_word = input('Enter a new word: ')
        old_word.append(new_word)
        words.append(old_word)
        if new_word in words:
            random.shuffle(words)
            print(words)
```

e.g
input `1`
`Enter a new word: lemon`

output  `'orange', 'banana', 'lime', 'apple', 'lemon','coconut', 'strawberry'`

Comment: ```int(input('Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: '))```. Your condition is never true because ```input``` returns a string, but you compare it with an integer

Comment: In the future, try to focus your question around the specific technical problem you encountered, not the program you were trying to write when you encountered it. The linked duplicate is a good example of doing that well (the code given is a proper [mre], and the title is narrowly focused on the technical issue that caused the question to be asked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction:

- It should be `int(input('Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: '))`. Your condition is never true because `input` returns a string, but you compare it with an integer.

Also, is `old_word` list for storing the new words? If yes, then you just need to add the element. Don't add the whole list to `words`

```
import random

words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'coconut', 'strawberry', 'lime']
old_word = []

while True:
    choice = int(input('Press [1] to continue [2] to exit: '))
    if choice == 2:
        break
    
    elif choice == 1:
        new_word = input('Enter a new word: ')
        old_word.append(new_word)
        words.append(new_word)
        if new_word in words:
            random.shuffle(words)
            print(words)
```

Comment: doesn't work exacty. when i enter **1**  and enter a new word it does not return the new word nor the words from the existing list @Sujay